# How to print desired amount of elements in an array?

Tags: c++, arrays, for-loop, arraylist

If I want to print a `single dimensional array` with `n` number of elements. Can I initialize the `array` as `array[n]` ?

```
#include "pch.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;

    std::cout << "Please enter the number of elements (n): ";
    std::cin >> n;

    int array[n];

    for (int i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        std::cin >> array[n];
    }
    return 0; 
}
```

Comment: 1) If you want to develop portable code: No, since VLAs are non-standard C++ (even though, they are supported by some compiler extensions). 2) Just use `std::vector`.

Comment: Even if you could use a VLA (aka `int array[n]`) in C++ - which you can't,  array indices are zero based in C++.   So printing an array with `n` elements require iterating from `0` to `n-1`  (e.g. `for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) ...`).    The `<=` in your loop means the loop passes the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In C++ you cannot initialize an array with a variable length. Either you:

- dynamically allocate memory

  `int *array = new int[n];`

  in which case you should not forget to deallocate later with

  `delete[] array;`
- Or you can use a `std::vector`

  `std::vector<int> array(n);`

  which will be deallocated when it exits the scope.

Additional mistakes are:

- The `for` loop should be like

  `for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)`

  because with n elements the array indexes go from 0 to n - 1.
- To read the input you can simply use

  `std::cin >> array[n]`

  The code you wrote with a combination of `>>` and `<<` cannot work.

Comment: dynamically is spelt with two y's, not one.

Answer (score 2):

As C++ does not support Variable Length Arrays (VLAs) contrary to C99, you'll have to use some other means of allocating memory of arbitrary size in C++ like `std::vector`:

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int n;

    std::cout << "Please enter the number of elements (n): ";
    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> foo(n);

                    // valid indexes range form 0 to size - 1: < n instead of <= n
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
        std::cin >> foo[i];
}
```

Also you mixed up `i` and `n` in your `for`-loop.

> ```
> std::cin >> array[n] << " ";
>                      ^^^^^^
> ```

won't work either.